# R - WordCloud2 does not always render the most frequent words

Tags: r, word-cloud

I use the `wordcloud2` package to render word clouds. It seems that `wordcloud2` does not always display the most frequent words.

I said "not always" because the problem is not permanent. It seems that the results are mostly random.

Code :

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(htmlwidgets)

DataCloud <- as.character(DataTextAnalysis[,1])
DataCloud <- as.data.frame(table(DataCloud))
DataCloud <- DataCloud[order(DataCloud$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),]
DataCloud <- DataCloud[1:10, ]
wordcloud2(data = DataCloud)
```

Data :

```
structure(list(`Theme 1` = structure(c(12L, NA, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
                                       NA, 14L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 
                                       NA, 12L, NA, 2L, 13L, 15L, NA, NA, 10L, NA, 1L, 2L, 16L, 6L, 
                                       1L, 7L, 9L, 15L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 2L, 17L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 
                                       2L, 8L, 6L), .Label = c("Ambiance", "Autonomie", "Changement régulier de hiérarchie", 
                                                               "Côté familial", "Défi", "Diversité des tâches", "Faire du bon travail", 
                                                               "Gérer l humain", "Gestion de projets", "Horaires", "Réglage du finisseur", 
                                                               "Relation client", "Rencontrer de nouvelles équipes", "Responsabilité", 
                                                               "Technicité", "Travailler avec la hiérachie", "Travailler en binôme"
                                       ), class = "factor"), `Theme 2` = structure(c(NA, NA, 13L, 1L, 
                                                                                     14L, NA, NA, 4L, 15L, 14L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 15L, 4L, 13L, 8L, 
                                                                                     6L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 11L, 5L, 5L, NA, NA, 9L, NA, 16L, 1L, 
                                                                                     7L, 8L, 5L, 19L, 2L, 8L, 11L, 5L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 
                                                                                     12L, 11L, 8L, 18L, 17L, 4L), .Label = c("Ambiance", "Amélioration", 
                                                                                                                             "Autonomie", "Confiance", "Diversité des tâches", "Être écouté", 
                                                                                                                             "Evolution continue de l entreprise", "Faire du bon travail", 
                                                                                                                             "Hiver", "Liberté", "Matériel performant", "Partager mon savoir-faire", 
                                                                                                                             "Relation client", "Rencontrer de nouvelles équipes", "Responsabilité", 
                                                                                                                             "Solidarité", "Stimulation", "Tranquille", "Travailler dans ma région"
                                                                                     ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Theme 1", "Theme 2"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                            -53L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reduce the font size so that all words fit the available page space:

```
wordcloud2(DataCloud, size = .5)
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to avoid setting the size for each plot ? I want to use this in a Shiny app with several texts so I'm looking for a general way and ideally that the user does not have to change.

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe ask the package author.

Comment: @Kumpelka hey, have you found a solution for your problem? I also would like to use it in a Shiny app.

Comment: It seems to render the data in the order of the data.frame. So I arranged my data in descending frequency, it might miss the later words but as long as the top ones are present I'm happy. df <-   arrange(desc(n))