# how to make wordcloud2 display top frequency words in r

Tags: r, text, word-cloud

I used word cloud and wordcloud2 on same dataset and find results are quite different. Word cloud show words with highest frequency first, while wordcloud2 seems to be sampling from different frequency bucket, thus high frequency word not necessarily show up. Some functionality of wordcloud2 is quite cool, but how can I make it show all top frequency words ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654007/r-wordcloud2-does-not-always-render-the-most-frequent-words

Comment: thanks. for letter cloud it stills seems to be an issue, if changing fontsize to very small, it could show top words, but some letter may not show up, guess just have to deal with  it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set the size to a smaller number:

```
wordcloud2(demoFreq, size=0.5)
```